# hide a div when scrolled to 100px refresh issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which would be hidden after scrolling to 100px but then if they refresh the whole page when the scroller is at 180px  or such its displaying, soon after i start scrolling it gets back to hidden.
how can i handle this situation of not to show even after refresh if the page is scrolled above to 100px
following is the script i am using to hide the div, what better i can do to this script to handle this issue

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>100)
     {
         $('div').hide();
     }
    else
     {
       $('div').show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must do the checking upon loading the document as well, you can do this with `$(document).ready`

```
(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        checkTop();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        checkTop();
    });


    function checkTop(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop()>100)
         {
             $('#selectorToYourElement').hide();
         }
        else
         {
           $('#selectorToYourElement').show();
         }
    }

})();
```

Comment: getting disturbance to other scripts on the page, can i restirct that to be functional to only that particular div?

Comment: what do you mean by 'restirct that to be functional to only that particular div?' ?

Comment: am using an another  plugin in that same page and that part of script is not working after adding those, so how can i sort out this??

Comment: I edited my answer, basically, added an IIFE to prevent global variables, can you try it again? :)

Comment: or possibly the problem is with the selector you used `$('div').hide();` you might want to use an id for that

Comment: no its still not working, am using a class in script

Answer (score 0):

made fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dauruk0512/do7w0oft/)

use class with height :100px and when scroll 100px, but change as you needed

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop()>100)
     {
        $('.a').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.a').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

and this is css

```
body {
    height: 2000px;    
}
.a {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not something i am looking for.